# Django display contents of list in a template

Tags: python, django, list, templates

I'm pretty new to Django's template system-
Basically, I'm trying to print out all the contents of a list that I'm passing to django in a context.

The relevant part of my urls.py is here-

```
 url(r'^class/$', twobooks.classes.views.getAllInformation, {'template_name':'classes/displayBooks.html'}),
```

Now, in my views getAllInformation is as follows-

```
def getAllInformation(searchTerm,template_name):
    nameAndNumberStore = modifySearchTerm(searchTerm)
    url = modifyUrl(nameAndNumberStore)
    soup = getHtml(url)
    information = []
    if (checkIfValidClass(soup,nameAndNumberStore)):
        storeOfEditions = getEdition(soup)
        storeOfAuthorNames = getAuthorName(soup)
        storeOfBookNames = getBookNames(soup)
        storeOfImages = getImages(soup)
    information.append(storeOfAuthorNames)#REMEMBER this is a list of two lists 
    information.append(storeOfEditions)
    return render_to_response(
    template_name,
    {'authors': storeOfAuthorNames},
    )
```

and displayBooks.html is as follows-

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<h1>Testing the class page backend</h1>
<ul>
{ % for author in authors|safe% }
    <li>{{ author }}</li>
{ % endfor % }
</ul>

</body> 

</html>
```

I think this is fairly simple, but I'm not sure what's going on, so thought I'd ask for some help - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter will turn *anything* into a string. If you start with the literal `[1, 2, 'foo', u'bar']`, you're going to end up with approximately the literal `u"[1, 2, 'foo', u'bar']"` (or something like it—I'm not quite certain of how it's rendered as I've never tried doing it; also I say "approximately" as it's actually a `SafeString` instance not a `unicode` instance). Then, iteration is going over each character in the produced string, which isn't what you want.

Instead, you can use the [`safeseq`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safeseq) filter which applies the `safe` filter to each element in the sequence,

```
<ul>
{% for author in authors|safeseq %}
    <li>{{ author }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Or, you could apply `safe` to the value inside the iterator.

```
<ul>
{% for author in authors %}
    <li>{{ author|safe }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I would recommend `safeseq`, as you may then be able to optimise the template further, if you wish, with the [`unordered_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#unordered_list) filter, if you only wish to display the values. (Note that I'm not certain of how it behaves—it's possible that this would unmark it as safe. You'd need to try it.)

```
<ul>{{ authors|safeseq|unordered_list }}</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you mentioned the data format for `storeOfAuthorNames`, the output you're currently getting, and what you're expecting instead.

All I can tell from your view is:

- `authors` (`storeOfAuthorNames`) is produced by `getAuthorName(soup)`
- if `checkIfValidClass(...)` returns `False`, you'll end up with a `NameError` when trying to reference `storeOfAuthorNames` since it will be undeclared

If I had to guess where your problem is based solely on your example template, I'd say your problem is with `authors|safe`. You'll want to apply the `safe` filter on the value you're printing out, not the list itself. i.e.

```
<ul>
{ % for author in authors %}
    <li>{{ author|safe }}</li>
{ % endfor % }
</ul>
```